# Weird, Random Mouse Movements and Clicks in Ubuntu 12.04.02 - Nvidia Related?

Tags: mouse, ubuntu-12.04, nvidia-geforce, display-driver

I had some Nvidia issues recently on my Ubuntu 12.04 desktop system - not a LAPTOP, so no touch-pad related issues... I tried everything I could think of, including purging all Nvidia drivers and reinstalling them. Nothing worked. I spent 3 days on the web trying different driver-related fixes. I could not use any features that required 3d Acceleration, eg, Compiz Wobbly Windows, etc...

So I backed up my data and reinstalled the OS. I began setting up everything and things were fine for a few days. Then, yesterday, I noticed the mouse suddenly moving in random patterns. Sometimes it even clicked links and opened windows... I thought it might have been a hacker and I suppose it still could be. But the behavior is seemingly random and it has been happening in a manner that is inconsistent with someone remoting into my system. Plus, I have remote access disabled and I scanned my ports and there is nothing out of place (that I could tell).

I investigated mouse settings, changed the mouse and nothing works. In fact, this symptom even happens when I unplug the mouse completely.

What is happening? I still suspect my video card, but I'm not sure if this is warranted or justified. I don't have a card I can swap out to do a quick test. So I'm trying to figure out if there is another way to diagnose this.

Thanks.

Comment: you installed a different/fresh OS and it didn't help -- it's hardware, and you already determined it's not your mouse.  You need to keep troubleshooting, or take it in for repair.  since you determined it's not software related, and you don't have spare parts to swap for hardware troubleshooting, then you're pretty much out of luck fixing it yourself.

Comment: You might be right. I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything else. I think I'll find a video card and test that in the meantime. I guess I'm also fishing for what possible hardware components can have this symptom? Thanks.

Comment: It does sound a bit like a prank, but pranks dont last that long do they?  unless you have a evil brother :-)

Comment: No prank, dude... Se my answer ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I've never seen this before, so this is a good post to have on the web in case others see a similar scenario. I probably should have mentioned that I was running a hard wired USB mouse and a wireless keyboard. As it turns out, after trying a new video card and a couple other things, I ended up calling it quits.

I booted up my laptop and hooked it up to the monitors I was using, and then plugged in the mouse and wireless keyboard, as if the system was set up like the desktop. And low and behold the odd mouse behavior happened again. Now, I'm certain my laptop is fine so I started checking variables.

I realized that if it wasn't the mousse, which I had checked already, then the keyboard was the last thing that was changing in this set-up.

I fiddled with the wireless keyboard module unit and the mouse pointer moved. I then unplugged the wireless keyboard, plugged in a wired keyboard and I haven't seen the weird mouse behavior since.

Then I checked the batteries and they had voltages of ~1.35 V, which is considered "low."